# how to compare a string with strings in linkedlist and insert the result as boolean into mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I have a table "MoviesInfo" with these fields: movieId, Action, Crime, Drama, Comedy, Horror, Animation, Documentary,....

I need to compare the strings that I get by crawling (movie genres) with the list containing all genres and insert '1' in the associated genre column if that string was in the list. For example, genres of the movie "the dark knight" are "Action", "Crime", "Drama". So, I want to insert '1' in the columns "Action", "Crime", "Drama" and insert "0" for the other columns.

This is part of my code where I got genres of movies:

```
  List<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
  .........
  Elements elms1 = doc.select("div.infobar");   
  Elements links1 = elms1.select("a[href]");
  for(Element link1 : links1){
      if(link1.attr("href").contains("/genre/"))
       {
            genre.add(link1.text());
        }
   }

   .....
   .....
   try{
    String query = "INSERT into moviesInfo (movieId, genre)" + "VALUES (?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString (1, ImdbID);
        preparedStmt.setString (2, genre.toString());
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
   }catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception!");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

I hope I could clarify my problem, all Ideas are highly appreciated,

Comment: Could you please simplify the problem you have. Now your question is vague. THe input you have and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc, That is about the normalization. One move could be in two gender category etc.

Comment: @Vash-DamianLeszczyński You mean that one movie could be in two genres. Just to clarify.

Comment: actually most of the movies have two genres. but myprofessor told me assign a separate column for each genre in your table and put '1' or '0' since we may want to select all movies by only one specific genre. Am I clear?

Comment: I frequent IMDB quite a bit, it is quite rare to have a pure genre movie. Some even have 3 or more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could solve my problem. I had to use linkedList and LinkedHashMap to store the genres. (I used linkedHashMap and NOT HashMap to keep the ordering). This is the new code which works well:

```
     LinkedList<String> genres = new LinkedList<String>();
        genres.add("Action");
        genres.add("Adventure");
        genres.add("Comedy");
        genres.add("Animation");
        genres.add( "Drama");
        genres.add("Romance");
        .
        .
        .

     LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> currentGenreHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
     String baseUrl = "http://www.imdb.com/title/"+ImdbID;

            try {
               org.jsoup.Connection con = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21");
              ....
              ..
                   Elements elms1 = doc.select("div.infobar");  
                    Elements links1 = elms1.select("a[href]");
                    LinkedList<String> currentGenres = new LinkedList<String>();


                   for (String g1 : genres){
                        currentGenreHashMap.put(g1, 0);
                    } //set the default to zero


                    for(Element link1 : links1){
                        if(link1.attr("href").contains("/genre/"))
                        {
                            currentGenres.add(link1.text());
                            System.out.println("generi: " + link1.text());
                        }
                    }

                    for (String genere : genres){
                        if (currentGenres.contains(genere))
                            currentGenreHashMap.put(genere, 1);

                        } //here I compare the genre that I get by crawler to the genres in the list and when they were equal it set it to '1'
                        System.out.println("movie genres:" + currentGenreHashMap);
                          ...
                          ...
                     try{
                        String query = "INSERT into moviesInfo (movieImdbId, Action, Adventure, Comedy, Animation, Drama, Romance, Family, Fantasy, Crime, Biography, Documentary, FilmNoir, Horror, War, History, Western, Musical, SciFi, Mystery, Thriller, RealityTV, TalkShow, GameShow, Short, Music, Sport, News, Adult, Lifestyle, Experimental, Commercial, country, trailerLink, storyline, posterLink)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
                        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                        preparedStmt.setString (1, ImdbID);
                        int count = 2;
                        for (String g1 : currentGenreHashMap.keySet()){

                            preparedStmt.setString (count, currentGenreHashMap.get(g1).toString());
                            count++;
                        }
                      preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need an DTO (data-transfer-object) that you can use to put the genre into.

---

**DTO:**

```
public class Genre {
   //Create boolean field values for all genre and initialize to false in constructor
   //Attributes and name
   //Create getters/setters for all field values
}
```

**Fill DTO:**

```
  for(Element link1 : links1){
      if(link1.attr("href").contains("/genre/"))
       {
            String genre_name = link1.text()
            Genre genre = new Genre();                

            if(genre_name.equals("Comedy") {
               genre.setComedy(Boolean.TRUE);
            }

            if(genre_name.equals("Horror") {
               genre.setHorror(Boolean.TRUE);
            }

            //Repeat for all genre...

            //Add genre DTO to database
       }
   }
```

Now when you add this genre to your database, just set '1' for when the genre is true.

Comment: The DTO should not be part of name, and the Gender as DTO Should has single field that contain its name eventually some other attributes. If something is can have attributes then that something should provide the data.

Comment: Now you have more issues ;-). You have two `genre`

Answer (score 0):

There a various of strategies to deal with case when a item mach various filtering categories.

**Be adding columns**

Each category is represented as additional column in data table, with value 0 or 1 for matching.

**By adding relations**

You create a table with mamy-to-many relation where you store the relation of item to category.

**By adding mask**

You build up a single binary value called mask, where each position correspond to category.

`DRAMA,COMEDY,SCI-FI,DOCUMENTARY` a mask for SCI-FI comedy would be `0110` and for drama `1000`.

**By adding denormalization**

You just store the values in single column, and you separate them with delimiter. Using regexp you can determine that item apply to such category.

---

Each method has pluses and minuses. There are various trade-off that should be considered before choosing the approach and it is very probably that i will have to be changed in future.

So instead of focusing on give DB strategy, you should select one of it. And create a simple API to it in your application. The logic how the movies are matched with categories should not be exposed, so you wold be able to change it fast.

`public Collection<Movie> findByCategories(Category... categories)` it is the final product.

What are `Movie` and `Category`

The Category represent simple object that describe the gender of movie.

```
class Category {

 private final String name; 

 public Category(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

 public String name() {
    return this.name;
 }

  //Override equals and hashCode
}
```

The movie represent the Movie so in its structure we should have some attributes.

```
class Movie {
  private final String title;
  private final byte   year;
  private Collection<Category> categories;

  public Movie(String title, byte year) {
     this.title = title;
     this.year  = year;
  }

  public boolean isCategory(Category category) {
     if(categories == null) reuturn false;

     return categories.contains(category);
  }
}
```

or

```
class Movie {
  private final String title;
  private final byte   year;
  private String categories;

  public Movie(String title, byte year) {
     this.title = title;
     this.year  = year;
  }

  public boolean isCategory(Category category) {
     if(categories == null) reuturn false;

     return categories.contains(category.name());
  }

}
```